# Скроллинг внутреннего дива

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как получить координаты видимой части дива через jQuery ? 
А потом от этого отталкиваться и сролить блок внутри этого дива.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Можете показать ваш код или рассказать о проблеме более детально? Что значит отталкиваться и скролить?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Osmanov/pen/RKGdGJ

Comment: Когда блок виден на 30%, то список внутри него начинает скролиться синхронно с всем документом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышли такие сложные вычисления.

1. Вычисляем, больше ли это, чем 30%: 
   Узнаём положение нижней границы (положение скролл + высота окна), отнимаем положение элемента от всего документа и всё это делим на высоту окна.
2. Вычисляем положение скролла внутри div: (от положения скролла окна отнимаем число, при котором div выглядывает больше чем на 30%) делим это на (от высоты документа отнимаем два числа, при котором div выглядывает больше чем на 30%) прибавляем (к высоте окна прибавляем остальные 70%)

```js
$(function() { 
  var posScroll = false;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pct = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $('div').offset().top) / $(window).height();
    if(pct >= 0.3){
      if(posScroll == false){posScroll = $(window).scrollTop()};
      var pos = ($(window).scrollTop() - posScroll) / ($(document).height() - (posScroll * 2)) * ($('div').height() + $('div').offset().top - posScroll);
      $('div').scrollTop(pos);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
body {height: 3000px;}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 1350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>item 0</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
    <li>item 12</li>
    <li>item 13</li>
    <li>item 14</li>
    <li>item 15</li>
    <li>item 16</li>
    <li>item 17</li>
    <li>item 18</li>
    <li>item 19</li>
    <li>item 20</li>
    <li>item 21</li>
    <li>item 22</li>
    <li>item 23</li>
    <li>item 24</li>
    <li>item 25</li>
    <li>item 26</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

В этих вычислениях чёрт ногу сломит. Главное понять логически, что должно отниматься и что прибавляться :)